# Faster method than parsing /proc/net/tcp

Tags: linux

I read info about current tcp connections from /proc/net/tcp
src ip, dest ip, src port, dest port, uid
I use this information to obtain user id which is owner of ip packet captured by pcap lib.

Is any faster method to do this? How to read this information from linux kernel, any lib?
Maybe some events are available when connection is created, closed?